# how can we connect sqlite using node.js?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

How to connect sqlite with node.js so that sqlite could be used as database for my project . To have datastorage in sqlite through node.js

Comment: You can use `sqlite3` module for node. Please, look at [link](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is a C library published as a single include file. Use the module [sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) for nodeJS.